# Theta join conditions

Tags: database, join, relational-algebra

The book says that I cannot make a relational algebra theta join (a join with whatever condition) on two identical relations, so let's suppose I have:

```
person(ssn, name, surname, age)
disease(ssn_p, gravity, code)
```

With ssn from person which is the primary key,
code from disease which is the primary key, and ssn_p the foreign key referencing person.name.

Can I do a join on two relations that have common fields?

So for example there are two relations (result of a select and a projection):

```
R1(ssn, name)
R2(ssn_p, name)
```

Can I do the join between R1 and R2?

Comment: This probably belongs on [cstheory.se]

Comment: There are many RAs (relational algebras). They differ in operators & even what a relation is. Give operator definitions & your reference for yours. Eg textbook name, edition & page. What book is your quote from & what are its algebra's relations & operators? PS Constraints need not exist, be known or be declared to record or query. Similarly, relational operators act on input values regardless of what constraints hold or don't hold. PS If you don't have symbols use words. But google 'unicode relational join'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do a theta-join when the relations share attributes. The reason is that the theta-join basically juxtaposes attributes. In other words, if `a1, a2, ..., an` are attributes in `R1`, and `b1, b2, ..., bm` are attributes in `R2`, then the result of a theta-join on `R1` and `R2` will be a relation `R3` with attributes `a1, a2, ..., an, b1, b2, ..., bm`. If `R1` and `R2` share any attributes, then `R3` will have duplicated attributes. Repeated attributes are not allowed in the relation algebra.

If you would like to do a theta-join when the relations share some attributes, you can do a rename operation on one of the relations, so that all attributes becomes distinct.